# Comparing Datetime in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, date, timezone, timestamp

Do I need to convert `TIMESTAMP` to `DATE` before doing a comparison? EX:

```
AND SORD.CREATED >= TO_DATE(FROM_TZ(CAST(TO_DATE('','DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS TIMESTAMP), 'Asia/Kuala_Lumpur') AT TIME ZONE 'UTC','DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
AND SORD.CREATED < TO_DATE(FROM_TZ(CAST(TO_DATE('','DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS TIMESTAMP), 'Asia/Kuala_Lumpur') AT TIME ZONE 'UTC','DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
```

Just looking for an opinion, since I'm still new and learning about databases.

Comment: what DB are you using?

Comment: @MarcoForberg TO_DATE() is an oracle or db2 function, but it looks like from_tz() is oracle only. Now tagged appropriately.

Comment: @MarcoForberg
Im using SQL Developer with oracle db

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell exactly what you database you are using.  From the functions in the code you provided, I am guessing Oracle?  Please confirm.

In general, I can tell you the following:

- You aren't passing any values.  The first parameter to `TO_DATE` is empty, and that would contain the string to convert to a date.
- You need to know what the values in your database are.  Is `SORD.CREATED` a `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP` datatype?  Does it keep UTC values?  If so, then yes, you should convert local times to UTC before querying.  If possible, you should do this outside of the query itself.
- If the values in your database are of type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`, then you can use a `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP` with the `AT TIME ZONE` function, like you showed in your question.
- Don't cast to/from a string unnecessarily.  If your source data is already in a `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP` datatype, there's no need to convert to a string.  Once a date is a date, you should keep it a date.  Introducing string formatting can sometimes introduce errors.

Comment: Yes. Im using oracle db. I know the inputs are empty. i was using this part of the code to generate report for a certain period. I know the database is using UTC, but not sure the data type is timestamp or datetime. Is there a way to confirm the data type?
I want to know whether a we can compare a timestamp and a datetime without error/offset occurred.

Comment: Only you will know what you are storing.  If it's not your DB, look at the table definition, and check some of the values.  Or talk to whomever the DB belongs to.